# type "adb shell su" in terminal (cmd in win or console in Linux ) let the terminal hang

Tags: adb, terminal

I just want to input more shell commands after typing `adb shell su`, but the terminal just return an "#".

It appears to be unresponsive to further commands.

How can I solve this problem? Recompile the `su` binary? Any other suggestions?

Other information: I use `ddmlib` to communication with Android phone, 
if I use `device.executeShellCommand("su", receiver)`, an exception occurs(*com.taobao.wireless.testlab.ddmlib.ShellCommandUnresponsiveException*).

Comment: Is this a programming related question?

Answer (score 1):

typing a command, such as su, after adb shell only executes that command and returns. What you probably want to do is type adb shell, then once in shell type su. You will probably need to allow super user permissions, depending on certain boot.img/kernel configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Superuser.apk installed? su is probably waiting for response from Superuser to prompt the user if the root access is granted.